# Objects not reallocating

Tags: java, object, linked-list

I've just started using libraries rather than creating everything from scratch but it's causing me some issues that I don't understand.

I've a link list that I'm adding 'information' - an object with variable 'age' and 'name' inside, but I'm confused.

```
  List<ClientInfo> list = new LinkedList<>();
    ClientInfo information = new ClientInfo();
    information.age = 44;
    list.add(information);
    information = new ClientInfo(); // without this line it doesn't work, but i don't get why it shouldn't
    information.age = 66;
    list.add(information);

    int age = list.get(0).age;
    System.out.println(age);
    age = list.get(1).age;
    System.out.println(age);
```

As you can see above, it's fully working, however, when I remove the commented line it doesn't work anymore, it simply adds 66 to both fields and I don't understand why as surely I can amend the information object without having to recreate a node?

Could anyone tell me why?

Comment: It doesn't add 66 to both fields, it overwrites the field of your object. You cannot store two distinct values in a field of the same object.

Comment: When  you add that line you create a new object which can store your new data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without that line, you only have one instance shared by both age 44 and age 66 - essentially the same object got inserted twice, and both have age 66, since that overwrites 44.

With that line, you created a second instance, although the same variable was reused, now it points/referes to a different object.

Comment: Well accept his answer then :p

15 reps is more than an up-vote